# Alternative to file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
$xml_file = file_get_contents(SITE_PATH . 'cms/data.php');
```

The problem is that a server has URL file-access disabled. I cannot enable it, its a hosting thing.

So the question is this. The `data.php` file generates xml code.

How can I execute this and get the xml data without doing the above method?

Is it possible?

Comment: Is SITE_PATH part of *your* site? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: It is part of my site. SITE_PATH = 'http://mydomain.com/';

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scrape websites when cURL and allow_url_fopen is disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880628/how-to-scrape-websites-when-curl-and-allow-url-fopen-is-disabled)

Comment: if mydomain.com is the same site that the code is running on, you shouldn't need to use a http:// request to load the file. In fact, doing so means you're ramping up your own bandwidth (the http request and response will both get counted twice toward your bandwidth total). Even if you need to execute a local PHP program and just get the ouput, there are other ways to achieve it that don't involve using http.

Comment: Have you tried using curl instead?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php). This function is an alternative to `file_get_contents`.

```
function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: but still I'm getting "CURL is not installed!" But I enabled php_curl and php_openssl extensions

Comment: "CURL is not installed" means that you need to install cURL.  

Which is a rare situation these days, most systems have it installed by default. Most dpkg-based distros serve a package called *php5_curl* that comes with the right dependencies and configuration directives.

Answer (score 16):

You should try something like this,
I am doing this for my project, its a fallback system

```
//function to get the remote data
function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (function_exists('curl_exec')){ 
        $conn = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,  true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $url_get_contents_data = (curl_exec($conn));
        curl_close($conn);
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        $url_get_contents_data = file_get_contents($url);
    }elseif(function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('stream_get_contents')){
        $handle = fopen ($url, "r");
        $url_get_contents_data = stream_get_contents($handle);
    }else{
        $url_get_contents_data = false;
    }
return $url_get_contents_data;
}
```

then later you can do like this

```
$data = url_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
if($data){
//Do Something....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you have URL wrappers disabled you should use sockets or, even better, the [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) library.

If it's part of your site then refer to it with the file system path, not the web URL. `/var/www/...`, rather than `http://domain.tld/...`.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is local as your comment about `SITE_PATH` suggest, it's pretty simple just execute the script and cache the result in a variable using the [output control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) :

```
function print_xml_data_file()
{
    include(XML_DATA_FILE_DIRECTORY . 'cms/data.php');
}

function get_xml_data()
{
    ob_start();
    print_xml_data_file();
    $xml_file = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $xml_file;
}
```

If it's remote as lot of others said [`curl`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is the way to go. If it isn't present try [`socket_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) or [`fsockopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). If nothing work... change your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to read XML generated from a URL without `file_get_contents()` then you'll probably want to have a look at [cURL](http://php.net/curl)

Answer (score 0):

If you have it available, using curl is your best option.

You can see if it is enabled by doing `phpinfo()` and searching the page for curl.

If it is enabled, try this:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, SITE_PATH . 'cms/data.php');
$xml_file = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```