# PHP file get contents, http version

Tags: php, http, file-get-contents

I'm using the file_get_contents function to control a client,
(e.g. `http://ip:port/?light=on`)

When using the corresponding command in the browser it works, when i use the same url in combination with file_get_contents function it doesnt work.

When i wireshark the requests i notice that the browser is using http/1.1 and file_get_contents is using http/1.0.

I believe that the version of http is the problem why my code is not working,

How can i change this version of http in de file_get_contents function? or work around it?

Comment: I would use a curl solution instead - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979802/alternative-to-file-get-contents

Comment: Are you sure allow_url_fopen is set accordingly? , also consider using curl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the HTTP version using a context:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('protocol_version'=>'1.1')));
file_get_contents('http://ip:port/?light=on', false, $context);
```

See also the full list of context options http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

Note that if the server uses chunked encoding, you must use PHP 5.3 or superior.