# I want to show current GOLD RATE from Gold Price India Site using PHP

Tags: php

Just want to show current gold rate from Gold Price India (http://www.goldpriceindia.com/) using PHP.

I have done to get data using file_get_contents() method. But its working on localhost but not in server. I want this on my FTP server too.

My Code:

```
$url1 = 'http://www.goldpriceindia.com/gold-price-kolkata.php';
$content1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$first_step1 = explode( '<div class="prc">' , $content1 );
$gold_rate1 = explode("</div>" , $first_step1[1] );
```

I am using PHP, I hope my question is clear if not I ready to explain again.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to post your PHP code. How are we supposed to guess what you're doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your web hosting service has disabled accessing remote URLs. Enable error reporting in the script.

Comment: Updated, please check it, Barmar.

Comment: Code looks OK, have you checked for errors when you run it on the server?

Comment: It's normal, but some web hosts may have it disabled to prevent their customers from attacking other sites.

Comment: When I run it server no data is receiving. But I am unable to see the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have error reporting enabled? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: So what is the second plan for it? I have searched too many for an api to get the data. But nothing is fruitful.

Comment: Thank for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be your server disabled URL file access may be you can try alternate solution to get file content.

[Alternate method to get file content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3979882/2745294)

```
   function url_get_contents ($Url) {
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('CURL is not installed!');
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
}
```

Comment: Usually if they disable URL file access, they also disable `cURL`, since the goal is to prevent accessing remote URLs in general.

Comment: You can make HTTP requests without cURL, too, though it requires allow_url_fopen to be enabled in your php.ini file. I don't think so they disabled CURL, cURL is a way you can hit a URL from your code to get a html response from it. cURL means client URL which allows you to connect with other URLs and use their responses in your code.

Answer (score 1):

100% working Code

```
preg_match('#Gold price today in India <b>\(Rs\/10gm\)</b> is <b>([0-9\.]+)#', file_get_contents('http://www.marketonmobile.com/gold_price_india.php'), $matches);
```

echo 'The price is: '.$matches[1];

Comment: '<?php preg_match('#SPOT GOLD<br><div id="gold_ask" data-source="lightstreamer" data-grid="bidaskrates" data-item="Gold" data-field="ask" style="color: rgb(0, 128, 0);">([0-9\.]+)#</div>', file_get_contents('http://www.ibplspot.com/index.php/C_booking/index'), $matche);'  this is not working can u see this?