# Get XML data from website inside PHP file (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, xml, internal-server-error

I need to get XML data from a website using an API key, and I'm using AJAX and PHP.
Here's my AJAX code (btw, the PHP file is inside a FileZilla server):

```
var xmlHttpObj=null;
var isPostBack=false;

function CreateXmlHttpRequestObject( )
{ 

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlHttpObj=new XMLHttpRequest()
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
    xmlHttpObj=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
  }
  return xmlHttpObj;
}

function MakeHTTPCall_Tags()
{     

  var link = "http://phpdev2.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~i110815/recebeXml.php";
  xmlHttpObj = CreateXmlHttpRequestObject();
  xmlHttpObj.open("GET", link, true);
  xmlHttpObj.onreadystatechange = stateHandler_Tags;
  xmlHttpObj.send();

}

function stateHandler_Tags()
{
  if ( xmlHttpObj.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpObj.status == 200)
  {       
      var selectTags = document.getElementById("tag");
      var option;
      var docxml = xmlHttpObj.responseXML;
      var nodelist = docxml.getElementById("name");
      alert(nodelist.length);
  }  
}
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * ");
    // pedido ao last.fm com a função file_gets_contents 
    // a string XML devolvida pelo servidor last.fm fica armazenada na variável $respostaXML 
    $respostaXML= 
    file_get_contents("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.getTopTags&api_key=4399e62e9929a254f92f5cde4baf8a16"); 

    // criar um objecto DOMDocument e inicializá-lo com a string XML recebida 
    $newXML= new DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1'); 
    $newXML->loadXML($respostaXML); 
    echo $newXML;
?>
```

I'm getting this error from the browser console: 
GET http://phpdev2.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~i110815/recebeXml.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
Anybody knows whats wrong?

Comment: Please do not change your question to ask about another error. Ask a new question instead. If you change the question to something else, given answers will no longer fit.

Answer (score 1):

Internal Server Error is just the generic name for a [500 HTTP Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes):

> 500 Internal Server Error
>      A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable.

You have to [check your webserver's error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log) to find details about the actual error.

Judging by the code sample you show, the error is likely because of this part

```
$newXML->loadXML($respostaXML); 
echo $newXML;
```

Your `$newXML` is a [`DOMDocument` instance](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It doesn't implement `__toString` so it cannot be echoed this way. You have to use

- [`DOMDocument::saveXML` — Dumps the internal XML tree back into a string](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php)

In other words:

```
$newXML->loadXML($respostaXML); 
echo $newXML->saveXml();
```

See my introduction to [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

On a side note: there is no point in loading the XML into DOM if all you want to do is fetch the XML from the remote API and then output it. Just do a [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) instead of `file_get_contents` and remove everything after the call.

If this doesn't fix the error, I assume your server has [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) disabled and you cannot make requests to remote urls. [You need to find another way of downloading the XML then.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880628/how-to-scrape-websites-when-curl-and-allow-url-fopen-is-disabled)

Comment: I commented xmlHttpObj.send(null); because that's where the error was, but without that line it doesn't do anything, so I presume I can't access the file in the server

Comment: @AdamSilva have you checked the server's error log like I asked you to do?

Comment: Ok, so I'm not getting any errors anymore, but my PHP file isn't receiving correctly the XML data from the website. I've already changed the PHP and JS files above

Comment: @Adam if my answer solved your Internal Server Error, I suggest you accept the answer and ask a new one about getting the correct XML data.